# C++ Win32 API Controls messages

Tags: c++, api, winapi

im starting with Win32 api, im adding a button control to my main window with the flowing code:

```
 HWND boton = CreateWindow(
    "BUTTON",   //
    "Caption",       // 
    WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Styles.
    250,         // x position.
    10,         // y position.
    100,        // Button width.
    40,        // Button height.
    hwnd,       // Parent window.
    NULL,       // No menu.
    (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),
    NULL);      // Pointer not needed.
```

how can i assign it an id, so i can get the message on the loop, in the message loop im trying to catch the message as WM_COMMAND but i don't get any result i've tried with WM_NOTIFY too.

Comment: oks5, welcome to StackOverflow!  Be sure to update your profile so we can get to know you.  If you desire to reply to these messages, the place to do so is back at the question where they are posted.  At the bottom of your own question and at the bottom of each answer is grey text which reads "Add Comment".  This will allow you to respond to comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assign it an ID, you have to use the `hMenu` parameter. If you have specified that the window will be a child (i.e. with `WS_CHILD`), the `hMenu` parameter will be interpreted as an integer ID for the window. Also, provide the `BS_NOTIFY` style.

```
HWND boton = CreateWindow (
    "BUTTON", 
    WS_TAPSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | BS_NOTIFY,
    250, 10, 100, 40,
    hwnd,
    (HMENU)101,  // This becomes the Control ID
    (HINSTNACE)GetWindowLong(hwnd,GWL_HINSTANCE),
    NULL);
```

EDIT: Special shout goes out to [Heath Hunnicutt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188704/heath-hunnicutt) for the info on `BS_NOTIFY`.

Comment: Hey maybe I should update my answer with the info on how to pass it in as an ID... :-/

Comment: BS_NOTIFY is only necessary if you want to receive notifications other than BN_CLICKED.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you do not need to specify an ID for the button.  The problem is your code is missing a style bit to `CreateWindow()`.

You must specify the style `BS_NOTIFY` for the parent window to receive notifications from Button controls.

You will then receive window message `WM_COMMAND` with `(HIWORD(w_param) == BN_CLICKED)` every time your button is clicked.  See the `BN_CLICKED` documentation for more.

Using a control ID is unnecessary because the `BN_CLICKED` message will provide you with the control's window handle.  Because you are already required to keep track of the window handle in order to properly call `DestroyWindow` when you receive `WM_DESTROY` comparing the button's window handle is just as easy as using a control ID.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I'm sorry for stealing your thunder. Have an up-vote. It's only 5 points short of an accept.

Comment: You dont need to destroy the window in WM_DESTROY. Owned windows are automatically destroyed when their owner is destroyed. If NULL was being passed to parameter 8 then sure.

Answer (score 0):

To set the window id, pass it in as if it were an HMENU:

(HMENU) nChildID